# How to have the controller render a different form through if-else statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to reconfigure my password reset functionality so that I can use it for an additional model. I've got it all working except one issue.

It is able to find the user by searching on both tables. It then sends a link such as `http://url/password_resets/Uhhi7Omp***pigTtg/edit?email=main%40example.com`.

But then it should render a different form depending on from which table the user is from. In the controller I just had:

```
def edit
end
```

But I now have two views, one for each type of user/table. I tried the following in the controller:

```
  def edit
    if @type1                  #This if statement works, also use it for other methods in the controller.
      render _to edit_type1    #Name of the view file
    elsif @type2
      render reset_type1       #Name of the view file
    end
  end
```

But since edit_type1 and type2 are unknown to routes, this doesn't work. What should I add to the routes file? Since the views don't have their own controller method, I'm not sure.

Routes:

```
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

Comment: Changing the routes to `resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit_type1, :edit_type2, :update]` doesn't work. I'm not sure why this doesn't create paths for edit_type1 and edit_type2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with routes - it's dispatched the request to the correct controller and action, so its job is done (until you need to generate more urls)

This should just be

```
render action: "edit_type1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create additional routes you can do

```
resources:password_resets do
  member do
    get 'edit_type_1', to: 'my_controller#type_1_incoming, as: 'edit_type1'
    get 'edit_type_2', to: 'my_controller#type_2_incoming, as: 'edit_type2'
  end
end
```

or

```
resources:password_resets do
  collection do
    get 'edit_type_1', to: 'my_controller#type_1_incoming, as: 'edit_type1'
    get 'edit_type_2', to: 'my_controller#type_2_incoming, as: 'edit_type2'
  end
end
```

The difference between `member` and `collection` being if you need to pass an `id` to specify a particular object or not.

... but I don't think you need to modify your routes based on how I read your requirements. You want to display different forms but come to the same `update` method?

Then both forms should have something like this...

```
<%= form_for :password_reset do |f| %>
```

And the forms will automatically submit to the password_resets_controller, the `update` method.